# Need to access year/month variable when grouping entries by date

Tags: entries, group

Having issues trying to access the year & month variable when grouping entries by month-year. The code is outputting the desired results (ie. December 2014), however I would like to format the url by 'year/month'.

#### Archives

Browse news & articles for the last year.

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(null) %}
<ul>
{% for date, entries in allEntries | group('postDate|date("F Y")') %}
    <li><a href="{{ year }}/{{ month }}">{{ date }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Both answers give me the desired results. Now I'm wondering what is the better answer? Paul's splits the `date` variable and Douglas use the DateTime object

Comment: Douglass is on the right track. You can *get* a DateTime to [re]format if you your year-month variable is in a format the `date` filter recognizes. I added a code snippet that I hope illustrates this helpfully.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, a simple hyphen would do the trick — "YYYY-MM" is a format the `date` filter recognizes.

```
{% set entries = ... %}
{% set entriesByMonth = entries|group('postDate|date("Y-m")') %}
{% for month, entries in entriesByMonth %}
  <li>
      <a href="{{ month|date("Y") }}/{{ month|date("m") }}">
        {{ entries | length }} entries in {{ month|date("F Y") }}
      </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I actually like Micahel's answer the best as there is no extra variables needed.

Answer (score 4):

The `year` and  `month` variables are not defined, so you'd first have to get these from the 'date' variable.

You could do this by using Twig's `split` function and splitting `date` by the space in between:

```
{% set dateParts = date | split(' ') %}
{% set month = dateParts[1] %}
{% set year = dateParts[0] %}

<a href="{{ year }}/{{ month }}">{{ date }}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest using twig's `date` filter to format the date as needed, but as Paul astutely pointed out in his comment, you don't really have a dateTime variable to work with.

So my answer is use Paul's answer. ;)

Comment: Douglas, am I wrong or is `date` a string, not a DateTime object?

Comment: It is. I noticed it as soon as I posted and fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Douglas, this wouldn't work. Your `entry` variable now contains all entries, so you wouldn't be able to get a `postDate` from it ;)

Comment: You're right Paul! Remind me never to answer questions before my first cup of coffee please.

Comment: Coffee? Just finishing my first glass of whisky ;)