# Dropdown that shows all months and when selected displays all entries from that month

Tags: filter, postdate

This snippet displays every post by postDate, which lists a bunch of “October 2015”. I am trying to filter by month/year, so only one “October 2015” shows then one “November 2015”, then one “December 2015” so on and so forth. So choosing the month, shows all posts from that month.

```
<div class="form-field select">
<label for="blog-date">by date</label>
<div class="custom-select">
    <select name="blog-date" id="blog-date" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
        <option value="/blog">All Time</option>
        {% cache %}
        {% nav entry in craft.entries({ group: 'blog', order: 'postDate desc', limit: null }) %}
            <option value="{{ entry.postDate | date('F-Y') }}"
                {% if craft.request.getLastSegment() == entry.postDate %}selected{% endif %}>
                {{ entry.postDate | title | date('F Y') }}
            </option>
        {% endnav %}
        {% endcache %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following three resources should be substantial enough to find a solution:

- [Linking and showing archive by month](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/11508/linking-and-showing-archive-by-month)
- [Craft Docs: Grouping by year and then month](https://craftcms.com/support/entry-archive#grouping-by-year-and-then-month)
- [Need to access year/month variable when grouping entries by date](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/need-to-access-year-month-variable-when-grouping-entries-by-date)